# How to apply diamond dust to a canvas?

Tags: paper, adhesives, diamond-dust

How can I apply diamond dust to a canvas or photo?   I've searched the web but can't find any information about it. I've used photo spray glue but it's too sticky.

Comment: What was the issue caused by the glue being too sticky exactly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "diamond dust"? Do you mean glitter?

Answer (score 7):

"Diamond dust" refers to glitter than is actually composed of crushed glass instead of the traditional shiny flecks of plastic. This differs from glitter in that it is composed of larger pieces and therefore has more problems with adhesion. My guess, based on the limited information, is that Summer Rose is having a hard time because the glitter is leaving gaps where the adhesion shows through and is too sticky?
To avoid this, there are a couple options.

**1. Use a better glue**

For glitter like this that is both heavier and larger, a more robust glue is needed. Instead of spray glue, try using PVA glue or hot glue. If you find these adhesives do not dry completely clear and do not offer the desired effect, there is diamond dust specific glue called [Diamond Glaze](http://www.diamondglaze.com/) which seems to be popular among crafters if you'll be using diamond dust frequently.

**2. Use traditional glitter instead**

Traditional glitter is cheap and super easy to use. It can be adhered with nearly any liquid glue. Just don't accidentally drop it on yourself.

[This forum on diamond dust](http://www.splitcoaststampers.com/forums/techniques-f11/how-apply-diamond-dust-t301896.html) also might be helpful to you where a similar question is asked. It's lengthy, but you might get some good tips outs of it!

Answer (score -1):

Make your own.
I buy my seed beads at the dollar store: sometimes at Walmart or in craft stores when on sale.
Use a coffee grinder, with different small shifters.
Wait until the dust settles in the grinder (you do not want to breath in any particles), then shift with the smallest shifter first, then the second, and so on. You'll get 3 to 4 different grits.

**To apply, use triple thick, or a Beacon glue product** (they are very good). You may want to buy the Christmas glass balls. Put them in 2-3 strong bags, secure and bang them to pieces: use a rolling pin to crush them to bits.
If you like, use a grinder's 1 to 2 pulse shift, then grind the larger pieces. I tell you: they look like German glass glitter. So save some money and DIY. Happy grinding!

Comment: This sounds absolutely brilliant and I'm totally going to do this, but the question is about getting the diamond dust to stick to a canvas. Do you have info about a good adhesive to use?

Comment: Answer does mention what glue to use, but it is buried in the grinding and smashing... maybe an edit so it better addresses the question? Plus keep that coffee grinder away from the kitchen!!!